# MockMvc test POST request

Tags: spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc, spring-boot-test

I have the following post route in my REST controller:

```java
     @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = 
    "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity saveMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
        movieService.saveMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The route uses a service to add the movie passed in request body in data store.
The signature of the service method is this:

```java
    Movie saveMovie(Movie movie);
```

I have written the following test and a helper method for it:

```java
      @Test
      public void saveMovie() throws Exception {
        Movie movie1 = new Movie();
        movie1.setImdbID("imdb1");
        movie1.setTitle("Meter");
        movie1.setYear("2015");
        movie1.setPoster("meter.jpg");

        when(movieService.saveMovie(movie1)).thenReturn(movie1);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/api/movie")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(asJsonString(movie1))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())                   
                .andExpect(content().contentType
                     (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
                 verify(movieService, times(1)).saveMovie(movie1);
                 verifyNoMoreInteractions(movieService);
    }



    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(jsonContent);
            return jsonContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
    Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
     com.stackroute.ng2boot.service.MovieService#0 bean.saveMovie(
       com.stackroute.ng2boot.domain.Movie@ae372b9
     );
     -> at 

     com.stackroute.ng2boot.controllers.MovieRestControllerTest.
     saveMovie(MovieRestControllerTest.java:129)
     Actual invocation has different arguments:
    com.stackroute.ng2boot.service.MovieService#0 bean.saveMovie(
    com.stackroute.ng2boot.domain.Movie@2098d37d
    );
    -> at     
    com.stackroute.ng2boot.controllers.MovieRestController.
    saveMovie(MovieRestController.java:60)
```

Except save and update, where I need to pass a Movie JSON as request body, the other routs are passing tests. Please share your valuable inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is the **MovieService** class:

```
@Component
public class MovieService {

    private static List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        Movie m1 = new Movie("id1", "title1","2000", "poster1.jpg");
        Movie m2 = new Movie("id2", "title2","2001", "poster2.jpg");
        Movie m3 = new Movie("id3", "title3","2002", "poster3.jpg");
        Movie m4 = new Movie("id4", "title4","2003", "poster4.jpg");
        Movie m5 = new Movie("id5", "title5","2004", "poster5.jpg");

        movieList.add(m1);
        movieList.add(m2);
        movieList.add(m3);
        movieList.add(m4);
        movieList.add(m5);
    }

    public Movie saveMovie(Movie movie){
        movieList.add(movie);
        return movie;
    }
}
```

And let's say this is the **MovieController** class:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieService movieService;

    public MovieController(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity saveMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
        movieService.saveMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

You could write the test like below using MockMvc. The test checks if the HttpStatus in the response is the expected one: HttpStatus.OK. And also check if saveMovie.saveMovie was called once for movie6.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MovieController.class)
public class MovieControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Test
    public void saveMovie() throws Exception {
        Movie movie6 = new Movie("id6", "title6", "2006", "poster6.jpg");
        String movie6AsJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(movie6);
        String url = "/";

        when(movieService.saveMovie(any(Movie.class))).thenReturn(movie6);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(movie6AsJson);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        int actualResult = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        int expectedResult = HttpStatus.OK.value();

        assertEquals("Result not as expected!",expectedResult,actualResult);
        verify(movieService, times(1)).saveMovie(refEq(movie6));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.refEq;
----
verify(movieService, times(1)).saveMovie(refEq(movie1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with:

```
verify(movieService).saveMovie(ArgumentMatchers.eq(movie1));
```

It would also be good to ensure that you have `equals` and `hashCode` methods implemented in `Movie` class.

Other small thing that I noticed (however, unrelated to your problem) is that you don't need to use both `times(1)` and `verifyNoMoreInteractions(movieService)`. `Mockito.verify` is by default expected to be called once. Take look at it source:

```java
public static <T> T verify(T mock) {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.verify(mock, times(1));
}
```